# How to count number of weeks in python starting from a month of August and adding up the number of weeks month after month

Tags: python, pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLxTG.png)For example, I have two columns and I want to create another column displaying the number of week.

Ex: 03 Aug 2018 it should give 1 week and so on.

I am using the pandas library to do that but it is numbering weeks from January, so I am getting the week 31 in august instead of getting 1st week in august.

I tried this:

```
data_18['App Start Week'] = data_18['Started Week'].dt.week
```

Which gave me the number of weeks starting from January.

And then I subtracted 30 from it to get the starting month as August to count the number of weeks.

But as the dates are going to next year again it is starting with 1st week and so on.

As the year is changing I am facing issues.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you post some example data (a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))? This sounds solvable, and it would be great for us to base something off your existing data and code.

Comment: convert to linux epoch for instance then divide seconds by number of seconds in a week.

Comment: Yes, Sure. I can add an Image of the data till I have reached in solving the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the difference versus a fixed date, convert to days and use floor division:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': ['08-03-2018', '08-20-2018', '11-11-2018',
                             '12-25-2018', '01-01-2019']})

df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])

df['week_num'] = (df['dates'] - pd.Timestamp('08-01-2018')).dt.days // 7 + 1

print(df)

       dates  week_num
0 2018-08-03         1
1 2018-08-20         3
2 2018-11-11        15
3 2018-12-25        21
4 2019-01-01        22
```